# Working with a client CSV file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

the csv file as `Sports & Pastime:Field Sports` in the classification row as you can see it's split by the : so what I need to do is extract that into two separate categories like so

Sports & Pastime as one category
Field Sports as another category

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very detailed, but the php explode function should be able to help you out with this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

just turn the file into a string an pass it through.

Comment: Yes I worked out I wasn't exploding the right string that was the problem now this is fixed